# How to tweet using twitter apis?

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to post to twitter using codebird.php. All the values are stored in a database, I didn't show the rest of the code here because I am sure it is working. However, I printed all the values for the community to see it.The problem is that when I used the library to tweet it does not post anything. Before I was testing getting the values from a form with method Post and it worked. I can't understand this error:

object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["code"]=> int(189) ["message"]=> string(22) "Error creating status." } } ["httpstatus"]=> int(403) ["rate"]=> NULL }

Please anyone

```
function twetting($value, $msg, $img, $link){

$values = queryTWTable($value);

        $consumerKey = $values['ConsumerKey'];
        $ConsumerSecret = $values['ConsumerSecret'];
        $accessToken = $values['AccessToken'];
        $accessTokenSecret = $values['AccessTokenSecret'];

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo "Consumer key is:".$consumerKey."<br/>";

echo "Consumer Secre Key".$ConsumerSecret."<br/>";

echo "Consumer acces token:".$accessToken."<br/>";

echo "Consumer acces token secret".$accessTokenSecret."<br/>";

echo "accouunt name:".$value."<br/>";

echo "message:".$msg."<br/>";

echo "image link:".$img."<br/>";

echo "link line:".$link."<br/>";


    require_once('twitter/codebird-php/src/codebird.php');
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey($consumerKey,$ConsumerSecret);
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

    $params = array(
        'status' => $msg." ".$link,
        'media[]' => $img
        );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
    var_dump($reply);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried posting first without media? Pretty sure, it's because the image.

Comment: @Tyralcori I found my error. It was the order of the variables in my twetting function, thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the order of my variables when I called the function:

```
$twitterArray = split(",",$row['TWitterAccounts']);
foreach ($twitterArray as $value) {
twetting($value,$row['Article'],$row['Img_url'],$row['Link']);


function twetting($value, $msg, $img, $link){

$values = queryTWTable($value);

        $consumerKey = $values['ConsumerKey'];
        $ConsumerSecret = $values['ConsumerSecret'];
        $accessToken = $values['AccessToken'];
        $accessTokenSecret = $values['AccessTokenSecret'];

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo "Consumer key is:".$consumerKey."<br/>";

echo "Consumer Secre Key".$ConsumerSecret."<br/>";

echo "Consumer acces token:".$accessToken."<br/>";

echo "Consumer acces token secret".$accessTokenSecret."<br/>";

echo "accouunt name:".$value."<br/>";

echo "message:".$msg."<br/>";

echo "image link:".$img."<br/>";

echo "link line:".$link."<br/>";


    require_once('twitter/codebird-php/src/codebird.php');
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey($consumerKey,$ConsumerSecret);
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    $cb->setToken($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

    $params = array(
        'status' => $msg." ".$link,
        'media[]' => $img
        );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);


}
```